# Apache Authentication Still Accepts the old password in the htpasswd

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, http-authentication

I run Apache on Ubuntu and use basic HTTP authentication.

I have a htpasswd file and there is a user named `scott` with the password of `tiger`.
However I changed the password to `tiger1`.

Now I can login using both `tiger` and `tiger1`. Even though I can see that there is only one line in the htpasswd file and the encrypted password has been changed after I changed the password.

What is the problem and how can I cope with it?

Comment: How did you change the password? And what does your htpasswd file look like? Did you restart Apache afterwards?

Comment: password created with htpasswd command. In the file, there is only one line, it says scott:somehashinfo. Yes, I restarted for several times.

Answer (score 0):

Check you `.htaccess` file and confirm the location of the `htpasswd` file .. maybe you are using 2 different files